# Function should not return a value if it doesn't exist in the function

Tags: r, function, environment

I'm writing a function that contains some conditions. The returning value of the function will depend on such a condition in a way that the returning value might not even exist within the function based on the condition. In that case, I'd expect the function to throw an error. However, this only works as long as the supposed-to-return value does not also exist in the global environment. If it does, the value from the global environment is returned, which I find confusing.

What am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?

**Example:**

```
xyz <- function(x = NULL, y = NULL)
{
  if (x+y > 10) {z <- x + y}

  return(z)
}
```

If I now run `test <- xyz(20, 30)` I get the correct result (test = 50).
If I run `test <- xyz(2, 3)` I also correctly get an error:

> Error in xyz(2, 3) : object 'z' not found

However, now I'm creating a z value in the global environment.

```
z <- 3.14
```

When I'm now running my function `test <- xyz(2, 3)` I get 3.14 as the result.

I was expecting that the function will only return the value of z if it exists inside the function. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a free variable (one referred to but not defined) in a function is accessed then it looks in the environment where the function was defined and then in the parent environment of that and so on.

Use `get("z", inherits = FALSE)` to look for `z` only in the current environment or check whether it exists `exists("z", inherits = FALSE)` in the current environment only.

Another possibility is to always give `z` a value:

```
z <- if (length(x) && length(y) && x + y > 10) x + y
```

In that case `z` will have the value NULL if the condition is false because the default `else` leg is NULL.  Returning NULL invisibly would be about as close as you can get to not returning a value.

```
xyz2 <- function(x = NULL, y = NULL) {
  z <- if (length(x) && length(y) && x + y > 10) x + y
  # other processing can go here
  if (is.null(z)) invisible(z) else z
}
xyz2(1, 2)
xyz2(5, 9)
## [1] 14
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just throw an *informative* error, based on the condition rather than `z`?

```
xyz <- function(x = NULL, y = NULL)
{
    if ( x + y <= 10 ) {
        stop("The sum of x and y must be greater than 10.")
    }
    return(x + y)
}

xyz(20, 30)
# [1] 50
xyz(2, 3)
# Error in xyz(2, 3) : The sum of x and y must be greater than 10.
```

Answer (score 2):

I like duckmayr's idea, but here's how you can implement while still using `z`:

```
xyz <- function(x = NULL, y = NULL) {
    z = x + y
    if (z <= 10 ) {
        stop("The sum of x and y must be greater than 10.")
    }
    return(z)
}
```

Comment: I like this too as it avoids doing the sum twice. Doesn't *really* matter, since this is clearly meant for scalars, but still...

Comment: Thanks... I probably should have just commented on your answer. If you want to edit I'll delete this one.

Comment: But yeah. In a case where the computation for `z` is non-trivial, this would be cleaner.